# Having trouble installing XDebug in PHP

Tags: php, xdebug

I try to config XDebug on PHP. I download the XDebug DLL from http://xdebug.org/. I tried every possible version, and edit the php.ini as it suggested, but when I use `phpinfo()` to see the xdebug info I get nothing at all. Any ideas?

My environment is PHP 5.4 + Apache2.2 + Windows 7.

Comment: And which system do you use? XAMPP? Wamp? Or Do you use another webserver?

Comment: Maybe you are editing the wrong php.ini? Check `phpinfo()` to see the path you should be modifying (you may have a separate one for the CLI).

Comment: also check your logs to see if there is problem loading the dll

Comment: try re-starting the webserver after changing the ini file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, follow these instructions on the [xDebug site](http://xdebug.org/wizard.php) to install the module correctly (Which I think you've done!.. *Use the wizard!!* ). (http://xdebug.org/wizard.php)

When you run `phpinfo()`, you should see the following (If installed correctly):

```
This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine: 
Zend Engine v2.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
with Xdebug v2.2.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2012, by Derick Rethans <-- !! :D !!
```

Then, you will need to add the following to your `php.ini`.

```
[xdebug]
# Make sure the below path is correct and points to your 'xdebug.so'
zend_extension="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.2.17/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613/xdebug.so"
xdebug.default_enable=1
xdebug.max_nesting_level=100
xdebug.remote_autostart=on 
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug" # I use netbeans IDE, so I configure this
```

**Remember:** After making any changes to `php.ini` you must restart your apache server.