# xdebug installation

Tags: php, xdebug

This is what I have in php.ini file under module settings:

```
[xdebug]
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```

and somewhere at the end of the file:

```
[PHP_XDEBUG]
extension=php_xdebug-2.2.1-5.3-vc9.dll
```

When I debug some php file from netbeans, the script does not stop at break points.. But after I click the stop button I see: **DEBUG SESSION ENDED** , so no errors..

Here is some information from phpinfo() that I think may be useful:

```
PHP Version 5.3.14

System  Windows NT TUGAY-PC 6.1 build 7601 (Windows 7 Home Premium Edition Service Pack 1) i586
Build Date  Jun 13 2012 18:50:12
Compiler    MSVC9 (Visual C++ 2008)
Architecture    x86
QUERY_STRING    XDEBUG_SESSION_START=netbeans-xdebug
REQUEST_URI /Framework/index.php?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=netbeans-xdebug
SCRIPT_NAME /Framework/index.php
xdebug

xdebug support  enabled
Version 2.2.1
IDE Key netbeans-xdebug
XDEBUG NOT LOADED AS ZEND EXTENSION
Directive   Local Value Master Value
xdebug.auto_trace   Off Off
xdebug.cli_color    0   0
xdebug.collect_assignments  Off Off
xdebug.collect_includes On  On
xdebug.collect_params   0   0
xdebug.collect_return   Off Off
xdebug.collect_vars Off Off
xdebug.coverage_enable  On  On
xdebug.default_enable   On  On
xdebug.dump.COOKIE  no value    no value
xdebug.dump.ENV no value    no value
xdebug.dump.FILES   no value    no value
xdebug.dump.GET no value    no value
xdebug.dump.POST    no value    no value
xdebug.dump.REQUEST no value    no value
xdebug.dump.SERVER  no value    no value
xdebug.dump.SESSION no value    no value
xdebug.dump_globals On  On
xdebug.dump_once    On  On
xdebug.dump_undefined   Off Off
xdebug.extended_info    On  On
xdebug.file_link_format no value    no value
xdebug.idekey   no value    no value
xdebug.max_nesting_level    100 100
xdebug.overload_var_dump    On  On
xdebug.profiler_aggregate   Off Off
xdebug.profiler_append  Off Off
xdebug.profiler_enable  Off Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger  Off Off
xdebug.profiler_output_dir  \   \
xdebug.profiler_output_name cachegrind.out.%p   cachegrind.out.%p
xdebug.remote_autostart Off Off
xdebug.remote_connect_back  Off Off
xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time    3600    3600
xdebug.remote_enable    On  On
xdebug.remote_handler   dbgp    dbgp
xdebug.remote_host  localhost   localhost
xdebug.remote_log   no value    no value
xdebug.remote_mode  req req
xdebug.remote_port  9000    9000
xdebug.scream   Off Off
xdebug.show_exception_trace Off Off
xdebug.show_local_vars  Off Off
xdebug.show_mem_delta   Off Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger Off Off
xdebug.trace_format 0   0
xdebug.trace_options    0   0
xdebug.trace_output_dir \   \
xdebug.trace_output_name    trace.%c    trace.%c
xdebug.var_display_max_children 128 128
xdebug.var_display_max_data 512 512
xdebug.var_display_max_depth    3   3
```

Thank you.

Comment: Check out my answer here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14159563/having-trouble-installing-xdebug-in-php/14159868#14159868

Comment: zend_extension = C:\PHP\ext\php_xdebug-2.2.1-5.3-vc9.dll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It needs to be loaded as a zend_extension and I recommend adding an ide key:

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="/usr/lib64/php/modules/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.idekey=xdebug
```

Comment: What is adding an ide key can you explain? And this .so file?

Comment: @KorayTugay `.so` would be the PHP module file on a Linux/UNIX system. On Windows, it would be a `.dll` file instead.